# MVC Drop Down List Core vs .NET Framework - Issue with View showing ID and not Text

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, dropdown, .net-5, scaffolding

I am having an issue using the scaffolding feature to generate views. The dropdown control displays the ID of the item from the other table rather than the text field. Using the same Models in both an ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) with MVC and an ASP.NET Core Web App(Model-View-Controller), the later displays the ID from the other table rather than the Text. It becomes time consuming going into each view to manually change for each dropdown. Does Core have the ability to perform the same scaffolding task the .NET Framework? Is there another step I am missing?  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```csharp
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int ContactSubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactSubject ContactSubject { get; set; }
}

public class ContactSubject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ContactSubject> ContactSubjects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How to do you generate it in asp.net core? I don't find any options about how to use scaffolding feature to generate Dropdownlist in the view, Can your show your step?

Comment: The dropdown is generated when the view is generated. I right clicked on the Controller folder and chose "scaffold" adding CRUD views, no other options used.

Comment: what's the version of your .net core and visual studio?

Comment: I am using VS 2022 Community Edition

Comment: you are using .net 5 or .net 6?

Comment: I am using Ver. 5.0

Comment: The automatically generated template has no way to determine the text value you need to bind, so you can only bind the Id. If you want to change it, I am afraid you can only modify the source code of the template.